# Migrating from parse - parse.com and Heroku+mLab both are responding after migration

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform

I have migrated my project from parse.com to heroku+mLab. After the migration task, I have created a new user which is showing both in parse.com dashboard and mLab Collections. The code (Android) I'm using for parse initialization is:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .server("http://myAppName.herokuapp.com/parse/")
                .applicationId("6CAUJ...............rlTZAdYie")
                .clientKey(null)
                .build());
```

**My question is:**

Is it normal to reflect the operation results in both instances? Shouldn't it be only reflected in mLab Collections after migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes even if you have migrated to your own server, you will be able to access parse.com dashboard GUI.
Currently your data is accessible from Parse API and your server's API both.

[Check this guidline](https://www.parse.com/migration)

After January or something, when Parse.com is completely down, you ll have to install on your own server/develop your own dashboard.

[Parse Server Dashboard Reference](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/)

Comment: `even if you have migrated to your own server, you will be able to access parse.com dashboard GUI` - I have gone through the migration guide, probably overlooked it. Can you refer me to the section where I can justify my query?

Comment: @SudipPodder: 
On this link I mentioned it is clearly writter: 

I HAVE FINALIZED THE MIGRATION. NOW WHAT?

At this point, your app is still hitting api.parse.com, but is using your MongoDB instance. You will need to administrate your database instance yourself, including maintaining indexes and scaling up.

Comment: So when `api.parse.com` will retire, I wont have any problem with the current code, right?

Comment: @SudipPdder: When the parse api retire, you won't face any problem. Just make sure your client library is redirecting to your server,not to parse api.